# System notification for hot module replacement WebPack ZSH

Tags: reactjs, webpack, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I have a legacy project which takes a lot of time to build. We are using [HMR](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) in development mode. However, I always have to toggle between the screens to check if the build is complete. I am using Iterm2 with [ZSH](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) and have tried [bgnotify](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/bgnotify) plugin for background notifications for long-running commands, it is great but it does not work for HMR. I also tried webpack plugin [webpack-build-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-build-notifier) but it also does not work for HMR. Can someone suggest a way to get system notifications on every HMR build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [webpack-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-notifier)
with config

```
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
........
.......
new WebpackNotifierPlugin({ 
   excludeWarnings: true, 
   alwaysNotify: true, 
   title: "App is build" 
})
```

Comment: add the config in plugins